# Zooming within UIWebView crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I've looked at 20+ different posts that are vaguely related to this and haven't been able to find a solution.

What I have is a class which subclasses UIViewController.  On this class's loadView method, I'm adding a UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView.  The UIWebView has scalesPageToFit set to YES.  The problem I'm facing is that it seems like zooms are being multiplied!  i.e. When you zoom inside the web view the very first time, everything seems to work properly.  When you zoom AGAIN, it seems that it takes your already zoomed version and tries to amplify that by an additional factor.  This causes the app to crash.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  I think something about the reported zoomScale from the UIWebView is messing things up.

Here's a modified sample code to get an idea of the current implementation:

```
# This is a UIViewController
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)loadView
{
  [super loadView];
  self.view.accessibilityLabel = @"MyView";

  self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
  self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
  self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
  // constraints removed from sample for readability

  self.headerView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [self.scrollView addSubview:self.headerView];

  self.bodyView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
  self.bodyView.delegate = self;
  self.bodyView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  self.bodyView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
  self.bodyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [self.bodyView.scrollView addObserver:self
                             forKeyPath:KeyValuePath
                                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                context:nil];
  [self.scrollView addSubview:self.bodyView];

  // other constraints here
}
```

Any help or feedback would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: why you want to add a webview into a scrollview?beacause a webview is already in a scroll view when you create

Comment: The whole view also needs to scroll and contains other pieces like a header view and a footer view (which are UIViewControllers).  Thoughts for disabling the zooming on the main view and only allowing it for the web view?